# Getting exeption after making socket connection in Android(java)

Tags: java, android-studio, sockets, connection

I have a working server, which was connected through web-site. I wanted to make android app, but had tested everything in JavaFX. So that it can t be becouse of server. I watched a lot of guides and all of them do the same thing as me) I posted my code, if you need anything else, write. Thank you!

MainActivity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import Base.BaseOutput;
import Base.BaseType;
import Base.IrrigationClockEntity;
import Base.IrrigationEntity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    boolean isIpOn=false;

    TextView textV;

    Button ent;
    EditText  enterURL;
    EditText  enterIP;
    Switch switchIp;

    BaseType bt = new BaseType();
    IrrigationEntity ie = new IrrigationEntity();
    IrrigationClockEntity ice = new IrrigationClockEntity();
    BaseOutput bo = new BaseOutput();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        ent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Enter);

        enterIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterIp);
        enterURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EnterURL);

        switchIp = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.SwitchIp);

        switchIp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                isIpOn=isChecked;
            }
        });

        ent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                bt.setType(1);
                Client cli = new Client(bt);

                if (isIpOn==false){
                    cli.setIp(enterURL.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    cli.setIp(enterIP.getText().toString());
                };

                try {
                    cli.GetData();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 //   e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                   // e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

                textV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textV.setText(Integer.toString(cli.bo.password));

            }
        });


    }}
```

CLient

```
import Base.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;



public class Client {
   private String ip;

    BaseType bt; // = new BaseType();
    BaseOutput bo = new BaseOutput();

    public Client(BaseType bt){
        this.bt=bt;

    }

    public BaseOutput GetData() throws InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

    Socket s = new Socket(ip, 10011);

    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

    oos.writeObject(bt);
    oos.flush();
    

    bo = (BaseOutput) ois.readObject();

    oos.close();
    ois.close();
    s.close();






        return bo;

    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.countryhouse">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

And the exeption:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.countryhouse, PID: 11469
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1156)
        
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
      
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)

at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)

at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)

at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)

at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)

at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)

at com.example.countryhouse.Client.GetData(Client.java:24)

at com.example.countryhouse.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:77)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4508)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18675)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

t android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`enter code here`

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11469 SIG: 9
```

If I delete uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" , I get such exeption
libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I tested this code in Javafx and everything worked well, so may be I have to connect some other libraries?

Comment: The key word in the error message is "NetworkOnMainThreadException" On Android, you can't use networked resources like sockets on the main thread because they can block indefinitely and make the app unusable. Search the internet/Android documentation for that key word to find solutions

Comment: This is bad practice in JavaFX too. The only difference is that it is not explicitly enforced.

Comment: Joni, thank you much! Now everything works clear